# Why object=null is used always?

Tags: java

```
MessageDigest md = null;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
md.update(saltBytes);
md.update(passwordBytes);
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

just like above，“MessageDigest md = null”，what is the meaning of the code?
I think "MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);" is better.

Why? there is much code just like that,Just because of the history?

Comment: Yes, do `MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);`. Doing `MessageDigest md = null;` first is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, this line is useless, in this context. Probably a sloppy or newbie programmer, or a quick refactoring where the developer forgot to merge these two lines.

Comment: It isn't 'used always'. Only in poorly written code. Do not imitate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks "why is this always done?" for something that isn't always or even commonly done.

Comment: potentially in this case the second and subsequent lines were within a try block and the value of `md` was beign used after the `try` block

Answer (score 3):

> Why object=null is used always?

It isn't "used always".  In fact, stuff like that appears rarely / never in well written / reviewed code.

Because ...

```
MessageDigest md = null;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
```

is directly equivalent to

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
```

> Why *[do people do that]* ?

No good reason.

> there is much code just like that,Just because of the history?

Possibly.

Also, possibly because:

- the author was not a good Java programmer ... or
- the author was in a hurry or didn't care ... or
- the code has been refactored using a (rather dumb) automatic tool and not tidied up ... or
- the code originated in something generated by a decompiler.

The only way to know for sure is to ask the author.

Comment: It often happens when the code has been refactored. Small stuff like this might slip through.

Comment: @marstran I've done my share of code refactoring without seeing anything like this.

Comment: @EJP I've also done a fair amount of refactoring, and I have seen this several times. Someone might for example find an unnecessary if-test containing some initialization code, remove it, and then forget to tidy up the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The null assignment is necessary if you use some conditional statement, you cant just write

```
    MessageDigest md;
    if (/*something*/) {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM); 
    }
```

You have to explicitly assign some value to your `md` variable. And null is used very often in this case.

In your example however, it's absolutely useless. Just write

```
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there such code? Because many people don't know the basic patterns of their programming language.

Why don't people know better? Because no one teaches them regularly. (Well, except that IntelliJ does, but that IDE targets advanced developers.)

Why does no one tell them? Maybe because their colleagues don't know it better either.

There are also people who document their getter and setter methods ("Returns the Name. @return the Name"). It's about the same.